# ASP.NET Hosting and routing

Tags: asp.net, hosting

Is it possible to host 2 asp.net projects off one ip address?  I don't have a domain name just an ip number.  I'm running IIS7.

The first project runs and displays fine over the web by simply typing in the ip address into the browser but I'm having trouble accessing the second.

Currently both projects have virtual directories in IIS7.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to host 2 asp.net
>   projects off one ip address? I don't
>   have a domain name just an ip number

Yes, you can vary the ports the two projects run under.  So your URL will look something like: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`

Comment: Or under different protocols.

Comment: Yes, that would work too.  I was assuming that they were both HTTP since he said asp.net projects.

Answer (score 1):

If they are in Virtual directories then you could just access them using the Virtual Directory name if you set it up:

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Application1/`

and

`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Application2/`